# Creating a digital twin of a moving robot in unity web server

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, mqtt, unity-webgl

First of all, I'm quite new to both unity and communication protocols, but I'm creating this post just to see if some more experienced people have any tips on how I can make my project possible.

So I'm creating a digital twin of a mobile robot in unity, and I want to be able to display the simulation in a webserver.

So I created an MQTT connection between unity and the robot database (using node-red), to get the x,y,z positional values of the robot, as well as the velocity (The data I send is in JSON-format if anyone is interested). Following this tutorial: https://workshops.cetools.org/codelabs/CASA0019-unity-mqtt/index.html?index=..%2F..index#5

This works fine in unity, and I was able to mirror the movement of the robot in unity, as it was driving around in the real world.

Now the next step is that I want to upload it, so that it can run in a web server. What I initially tried was to just build WebGL. The problem I encountered was that M2MQTT doesn't support WebGL, and the broker is waiting raw TCP connections on the port, while you can do only websocket connections in WebGL.

I also looked at WebRTC, to just mirror what happens in unity, however this requires unity to run for it to work, which is not what I want. This would be fine if there was any good way to unity in Docker, but didn't find any good solution.

So what I have been looking at lately is the use of netcode for game objects in unity. I have barely scratched the surface of it, but it seems like it could be a potential solution. Does anyone have any experience with this, that can point me in the right direction on what approach I should take on this.

p.s. sorry if I the details was a little unspecific, I'm quite a beginner in this
Thank you

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-multiplayer-in-webgl.1329621/

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://hyperdramatik.net/mediawiki/index.php?title=MQTT_implementation_in_Basic_Multiplayer_via_webGL_Client (it uses Mirror as networking solution and simply introduces an additional server which runs on Linux, uses the mirror multiplayer and connects to your robot via the usual sockets )

Comment: What exactly is the question here? " Does anyone have any experience with this" is not a question that can be answered here, SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Im sorry if i was unclear. what i was trying to do was not to ask a specific question, rather ask if someone with experience in unity could refer me or give any tips on what approach would be reasonable.

Comment: I made a video of what i have done so far, if someone is interested

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NCK1_Gycps

Comment: what exactly happening in the webgl? Did you see the console of the web for potential errors? I guess it is behind the scenes using threading and threads are not supported on the browser.

Comment: Launching the "game" in WebGL works fine, except connecting to the broker. So im not able to recive the data i need in webGL, only in the unity editor scene. I have been looking at websockets recently, as  people has adviced me that it might be a solution. However im not sure how the communication protocols work when you build and run to WebGL.

Answer (score 1):

that's correct, you cannot use the M2MQTT library on WebGL. WebSocket is what you need. The easiest way is to use a JS based MQTT library (e.g. [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs)). Unity3D cannot run JavaScript code, but you can create a "bridge" between your Unity C# scripts and MQTT.js using a [JS library interface](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html).
I created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ucl-casa-ce/unity-webgl-mqtt) with instructions, sample project and a demo.

> NOTE: the JS library will only run in the Unity WebGL build and not in the UnityEditor.

#### JS Library

- In the *Assets* folder of the Unity project, create a new folder named *Plugins*.
- Create a new JavaScript file named `mqttjsPlugin.js` within the *Plugins* folder (you probably need to create from Explorer or from your code editor, e.g. VSCode). The JavaScript library must have a specific syntax to be recognized and utilized by Unity.

> NOTE: The JavaScript file must have the extension `.jslib`. But creating a file in VSCode initially as `.js` allows you to have IntelliSense and colour coding (just useful to spot any error).

```
var mqttjsPlugin={

$DataMqttJs: 
{
    out_msg:"",
    topic:"",
},

mqttConnect: function (brokerAddress,topicSub,callback)
{
  console.log("Connecting to broker");
  var client = mqtt.connect(UTF8ToString(brokerAddress));
  var topic= UTF8ToString(topicSub);
  console.log(topic);

  client.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connected");
    client.subscribe(topic);
    client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    //Called each time a message is received
    console.log('Received message:', topic, message.toString());

    SendMessage('mqttResponse', 'GetData', message.toString());
    })
    });

client.on("error", (error) => {
  console.log(error);
  });
  },
  }
autoAddDeps(mqttjsPlugin, '$DataMqttJs');
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, mqttjsPlugin);
```

- If multiple functions are used (this is not the case) and data needs to be shared among them (not in this example), global variables can be declared using the `$Name_Context` syntax and registered using `autoAddDeps` method. To use them, you will need to access them using `Name_Context.Name_Variable`, omitting the `$` sign. (I left those variables 'out_msg' and 'topic' in just to show the syntax, they are not used in this example).

The function *mqttConnect* :

- Creates the *MQTTJs client*.
- Subscribes to the provided topic.
- Retrieves the MQTT data and send a message to Unity using *SendMessage*.

In this case, the broker address and the topic are sent to the library from the `C# script` (we will see this shortly). Numeric types do not require any conversion. However, strings need to be converted using the `UTF8ToString` method.

Finally, the [SendMessage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) method is used to send the data back to the `C# script`.

The syntax used is `SendMessage(objectName, methodName, value);` where:

- `objectName` refers to a GameObject in the scene. The name must be **unique** as Unity performs a `GameObject.Find` operation behind the scenes.
- `methodName` refers to the method of the `C# script` that is attached as a component to the `objectName`.
- `value` is the data sent to Unity from the JS library. It can be a string or a number. Arrays are not supported, but it is possible to send multiple values using JSON. The value can be empty.

The last line of the JS library is `mergeInto`, which is used to export the library in the WebGL build.

#### C# Component

To utilize the JavaScript library with Unity, you should create a new C# script,  name it `mqttManagerJS.cs`. Please note that this script should **not** be created in the *Plugins* folder (but I am not sure if the Plugins folder is still mandatory)

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using TMPro;

//Version 3
public class mqttManagerJS : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string brokerAdress = "wss://ADDRESS.mqtt.BROKER:8081"; //wss needed if served from HTTPS, port might change depending on your broker
    public string topicSub = "TOPIC/To/Subscribe";
    public TextMeshPro valueMqtt; //just using a TextMeshPro to visualise the data

    // Import the external JavaScript functions
    [DllImport("__Internal")] private static extern void mqttConnect(string broker, string topic);

    private void Start()
    {
        mqttConnect(brokerAdress, topicSub); //this call the Javascript method
    }

    public void GetData(string message) //this is called from Javascript using the SendMessage method
    {
        Debug.Log("Received string from JavaScript: " + message);
        valueMqtt.text = message;
    }
}
```

- The `[DllImport("__Internal")]` attribute is used to import the functions declared previously in the JS Library.
- In the `Start` method, the component calls the JS function and passes the broker address and topic to subscribe to.
- In the JS library, the `GetData` method is called, and the MQTT message is passed to Unity.

#### Visualise the Data

In this example, a TextMeshPro GameObject is used to visualize the message in Unity:

- Create a new `TMPro` GameObject by navigating to `GameObject -> 3D Object -> Text - TextMeshPro`.
- Right-click on it from the *Hierarchy panel* and rename it from `Text (TMP)` to `mqttResponse`.

> NOTE: The name needs to be **unique** as it is used in the `SendMessage` method in the JS library.

- Adjust the position and font size of the *mqttResponse* GameObject as needed to keep it visible to the camera.
- Attach the `mqttManagerJS.cs` to the *mqttResponse* object as a new component.
- From the *Hierarchy panel*, drag and drop the *mqttResponse* GameObject itself to the *Value Mqtt* field.

#### Build the WebGL App

Navigate to `File -> Build Settings`, add the *Open Scene*, and press `Build`. Unity will then create a folder containing the `index.html`, entry point of our App, and the data folders.

> NOTE: remember to set the public variables *Broker Address* and *Topic Sub* of the `mqttManagerJS.cs` component attached to the `mqttResponse` TextMeshPro GameObject.

The final step is to add the `MqttJs` library, which is called by the JavaScript library we created, to the head of the `index.html` file created by Unity.

```html
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/mqtt@4.3.7/dist/mqtt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The `index.html` file will run the Unity WebGL application that displays and updates the MQTT message received in real time.

> NOTE: By default, Unity builds use `GZ compression`. If the webserver is not properly [configured](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-server-configuration-code-samples.html) or if you are running a local web server, it will throw an error (`Unable to parse Build/XXXX.framework.js.gz!`). In such cases, you can disable the compression by navigating to `Project Settings -> Player -> Publishing Settings -> Compression Format -> Disabled`. `GitHub Pages` doesn't support gzip's content.

#### Common Mistakes

- The name of the GameObject used in `SendMessage` is not unique or it is wrong.
- The data type sent using `SendMessage` does not match the type received by the C# Script (string and number).
- There are typos in the GameObject name or Method name, particularly with regard to case sensitivity.
- The JS library is not properly formatted or has an extension other than `.jslib`.

Hope this helps (and thanks for using our Tutorial :) )